# How to get img from HTML doc

Tags: php, html

let's say taht I have a html code on a variable with only one img on it.
And i want to save the img on variable and later on use it with Tesseract.
How i am getting this img? ( this is the only img on the doc for sure)

Thanks!

Comment: `document.images[0]`

Answer (score 1):

This would get you the source-uri for the first `<img>` tag on the document.

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src);
```

```html
<img src="some_image.png" />
```

Comment: There is a way in php?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) or [google it](https://www.google.ro/search?q=parse+html+with+php)